# Which user will be get from session when concurrency control failed in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Says that we have this codes in a Spring MVC web application:

spring-security.xml

```
<sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/session_timeout">
    <sec:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" expired-url="/session_conflict"/>
</sec:session-management>
```

and in a controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/session_timeout")
public String sessionTimeout(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
   // ---- (A)
} 

@RequestMapping(value="/session_conflict")
public String sessionConflict(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
   // ---- (B)
}
```

With this settings, my questions is:

1. When a user (User A) is logged in, and another user (User B) is trying to login with the same userID, `sessionConflict` will be called and the first user (User A)'s session will be destroyed.
2. in place (A), can I get the user's info who is timeout?
3. in place (B), which user's info will be get in `userDetail`? User A or User B?
4. I am trying to get the destroying user's information so that I can mark them offline. If I cannot in question 2 and 3, is there any other way to do that?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Why are you trying to do 4, spring security already updates the session, looks like you are trying to do the job spring security is doing for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. Because I need to do something special like updating database when a user is timeout or kicked off by another user.

Comment: A user will not be kicked out by another user only by the same user. User a logs in User A logs in again, destroys first session. SO it is the same user. Your controller won't work because there is no one authenticated so you will never get the user details at least for option B. But as mentioned Spring Security already triggers those things, so not sure why you would need to do it yourself again. To handle session timeouts better use a listener for the `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` instead of trying to hack that together in a controller. But still seems like you are doing Spring Security's job.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot. Yes, It is same users just different sessions. Sorry for my bad expression.  You are right, in place B, I can not get the `userDetails` because it is `null`. As my previous comment said, I need to update database to increase a `concurrency error times` flag when someone use the same userId logged in.  Spring can not do that for me, How can I implement this requirement?

Comment: And as I previously mentioned Spring Security already does that for you. I you have some custom stuff for the session time out use a listener not a controller (as that would be only be invoked if an action was done, not if the user doesn't do anything). react to the events not to a might be possible optional thing that might happen. Also when the user logs in the next time (ie concurrent logins) then he isn't offline...